# Is there a way to do a sumproduct within a query function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Here's my current formula:

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    QUERY(
        'Sheet1'!A5:CR,
        "SELECT SUM(N)*SUM(D)/SUM(D)
         WHERE CR IS NOT NULL AND D IS NOT NULL AND N != 0
         GROUP BY CR
         LABEL SUM(N)*SUM(D)/SUM(D) ''"
    )
)
```

Sheet1 has individual dates in column A. in CR, I'm pulling the date that's the beginning of the week. I'm wanting to do a sumproduct that compares the individual results in N and D, eventually grouping them into one lump sum for the weekly total.

For reference, if I do `SUMPRODUCT(N2:N6,D2:D6)/SUM(D2:D6)` that works, but I'm working with a lot of data, so I want to only use one formula and pull an entire array for my weekly values. Thoughts?

I've tried simply using N*D/D but since I need to group by CR, I have to use aggregate functions, so right now it's like I'm only selecting the SUM(N) rather than comparing and dividing each day. I need to do this because I'm dividing call volume by the service level. We receive a lot more calls on Mondays than we do Saturdays, so I can't just do a simple average.